# Page count change after refresh the page in datatable

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have created a datatable using jquery with pagination feature. Everything is working fine. There is only one problem. When I refresh the page, page count increases.

**For example**, if my table has 30 records initially and I am displaying 10 records per page. Then initial page count is 3 which is correct. But as soon as I refresh the page, page count increase and it become 6 and so on.

Below is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#md-transaction-table').dataTable({
            "data":json,
            "bSort":false,
            "pagingType":"full_numbers",
            "pageLength": 8,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "paymentDate"},
                {"data": "description"},
                {"data": "statementNumber"},
                {"data": "transactionId"},
                {"data": "amount"},
                {"data": "paymentMethod"},
                {"data": "user"},
                {"data": "paymentStatus"}

            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
                ]

        }); // End of datatable function 

});
```

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: you are creating two datatables, one `$('#md-transaction-table').dataTable({})` and other `$('.dataTable').dataTable()`.. why?

Comment: What data is shown on the extra pages that are created? Is it duplicate data? Are the number of records per page changing? Basically, can you provide more detail on the specifics of what data is being added to your table (if any) on page reload?

Comment: Another note, you're using `bSort` which is the pre 1.10 notation (though it will work).

Comment: @user55: I wrote this line by mistake.."$('.dataTable').dataTable();" edited the code.

Comment: @ChrisH. When extra pages are created then those page shows duplicate data. And, number of records per page is not changing.

Comment: @Teddu Where does `json` come from? How is that data generated?

Comment: @ChrisH. this json has bean class object. Where I am generating records from back end and parse it into json obhect and send it to my html file.

Comment: @Teddu I'd take a look at it as a possible source of the error (maybe post it here). You say this issue occurs when the page is refreshed, but when the page is refreshed the previous DataTables ceases to exist and is replaced by a new one, so it's likely that your backend is generating double rows on a new request.